# Bulid starts, succeeds, but fails to create DB with Sqlite in dotnet cli

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to build a simple database code first using SQLite and dotnet 3.1

I've updated dotnet-ef tool globally and still get:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

This is happening on multiple projects (completely different associations) so it appears to be something on my machine but the error isn't hugely helpful, I'm running this on Mac. Previously this has been fine.

The VS Code output window doesn't show anything and all of the projects build without issue and nothing is reported as syntax errors.

Is there anywhere I can find logs that would give me more insight?

Comment: Any clues here? https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6733

Comment: Not really, sadly, I triied getting the trace file but nothing's returned, dotnet --help still works so in someways I guess that's good but in no way helpful as my APIs need databases. Thinking about removing all of dotnet from my Mac and reinstalling it. But would like to know the reason.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps you.
I hade the same problem and figure out that I needed to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` to show error message.
Please install this package and then run again the `migrations` command.
I believe this would help you.